# expected ';' after top level declarator

Tags: c, debugging, cs50

i'm having the following error:
expected ';' after top level declarator

and i'm not too sure what's wrong with the line of code. I'd really appreciate whatever help and assisatance that i am provided with. In particular, this is extrcted from a problem set.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int get_positive_int(string prompt);
string hash_table(int) 


int main(void)
{
  int i = get_positive_int("Positive Integer: ");
  printf("%i\n", i);

}

// Prompt user for positive integer 
int get_positive_int (string prompt)
{
  int n; 
  do
  {
    n = get_int("%s", prompt);
  }
  while (n <0 || n > 8);
  return n;
}

string hash_table(int)   
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)    
        {
            printf("#");    
        }
        printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: `string hash_table(int) ` is missing a `;`

Comment: but the problem persists even after adding an ;

Comment: Sure it's not a different problem? Post the full error message (including the line number)

Comment: Error messages have line numbers included. You should tell us the numbers or even better add a comment in your code.

Comment: This forward declaration is missing a ";": `string hash_table(int)`. The second problem I see, is that `n` is not defined in the function: `hash_table(int)`. And it also doesn't return anything btw.

Comment: There are a lot of errors with this code. Functions not returning anything, even though they are declared non-void. What is a `string` in C? Surely we're not talking about C++ `std::string`'s here ?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `;` at the end of line 5.